# How to make a Cog a prefix command group?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Cog the "root group" for the commands it provides. The following is a pseudo example and doesn't actually work, but hopefully illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.GroupCog, name='cog'):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @MyCog.command()
  async def cmd1(self, ctx):
    await ctx.reply('cmd1')

  @MyCog.command()
  async def cmd2(self, ctx):
    await ctx.reply('cmd2')
```

I tried a couple of variations of this that are syntactically correct, but wasn't able to get any of them to work exactly how I wanted. Here are two main constraints:

1. I'd like to be able to invoke the commands like follows:

```
!cog cmd1
!cog cmd2
```

2. I want the cog/command group to present in the help command like follows:

```
cog
  cmd1 Cmd1 description
  cmd2 Cmd2 description

someothercog
  cmd1 Cmd1 description
  cmd2 Cmd1 description
```

Now I know that I instead of using `GroupCog` I could just define a regular command group within the `Cog` using the `@commands.group()` decorator and call it `cog` to get the invocation signature I want, but when I use the default help command with that setup, I would get an output like

```
cog
  cog Cog group description

someothercog
  someothercog SomeOtherCog group description
```

It wouldn't treat the groups as "root elements", but the cogs. Each cog would only have a single group. It would be much more useful if it treated the groups as "root elements". That's essentially what I am trying to achieve.

Is there a way to do this using either `GroupCog` (which appears to be intended only for application commands, but not for prefix commands) or some other way? Or am I thinking about this completely wrong? Maybe I should explore writing my own help command instead to get the formatting and output I am looking for?

**Edit**:

This is how my !help menu currently looks like:

[image: Current Help Menu]

Each of those commands under each of those cogs/categories is a Group. I would like to list the commands contained within those groups under the category instead of the single Group command. I now believe the best way for me to achieve this is to simply alter how `DefaultHelpCommand` prints the bot help. I was trying to achieve that by inheriting from it and overriding the `get_bot_mapping` method, just to realize that `DefaultHelpCommand` [ignores](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/help.py#L1234-L1262) the `mapping` argument passed to `send_bot_help` and constructs it's own list of cogs/commands, making this particular approach a futile exercise.

Comment: This sounds like multiple questions here. Just want to make sure: Are you trying to implement a Cog system into your bot and don't get it to work?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dominik. No, my main intention is to make a Cog also be a Group at the same time, because the way I am structuring my bot is to have several cogs that each provide a single group command. I want to be able to invoke commands using the `!groupname commandname` pattern but want the DefaultHelpCommand to render either the group name or the cog name as the "category" and then list the subcommands of the single group in the cog's group command. Otherwise `!help` will render a list with Cog names that then each will only list a single group command. Does this help?

Comment: I updated the original question with an edit to hopefully provide some more insight. I agree that I probably thought about this problem from the wrong direction originally, trying to adjust the structure of my Cogs/Bot to achieve the output in the help command I wanted, instead of trying to change how the help command is printed.

Comment: I also filed a bug with discord.py since it seems like `DefaultHelpCommand` *should* use `get_bot_mapping`: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/9329

Comment: Sounds like you are doing too much work for such a simple thing. You correctly pointed out that you can use `@commands.group()`. Sounds like you just want to use this because of your help command? If that's the case, you can modify the help command and make your "own" to overcome your unwanted experience.

Comment: This is the modified help I came up with: https://gist.github.com/DanielBaulig/e7ecb24ad7f0d92882ec3faa0b9aaba2
It will show the commands of a Group command if any given Cog only has a single top level group command and the Cog and the Group command share the same name. Note that it depends on the PR that makes DefaultHelpCommand use get_bot_mapping.